# Количество созданий новых строк в куче

Tags: java, строки, heap

Один из вопросов в OCA7 выглядит так:

```
public class Mounds {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String s = new String();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        s += " " + i;
        sb.append(s);
    }
    // done with loop
} }
```

> Если сборщик мусора не будет работать во время исполнения кода, сколько примерно объектов будет существовать в памяти, когда цикл завершится?
>
> A. Меньше 10;
>
> B. Примерно 1000;
>
> C. Примерно 2000;
>
> D. Примерно 3000;
>
> E. Примерно 4000.

Со StringBuilder все понятно: он mutable, как создался, так один и остался.
А поскольку String является immutable классом, каждый раз создается новый объект. Сперва я подумал, что правильный ответ - B, 1000 объектов по количеству итераций. Но потом присмотрелся к телу цикла:

```
s += " " + i;
```

Здесь мы видим, что каждый раз к пробелу (который создается в пуле строк лишь единожды) каждый раз конкатенируется значения i, которое, соответственно, каждый раз создает новую строку со значением i, то есть "0", "1", "2" и так далее, которые затем превращаются в новые строки "0", "0 1", "0 1 2" и так далее. И подумал, что правильный ответ - C, 2000 объектов - по одному на каждую новую строку s и каждую новую строку значения i.

Однако в книжке приводится, что правильный ответ - B. Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем я ошибся?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор += можно расписать так s = s + " " + i;
Поэтому на каждой итерации будет создаваться по одной строке и присваиваться переменной s. Т.е. Java сразу сложит все в одну строку вместо того, чтобы создавать её по частям. Если бы мы вынесли " " + i в отдельную переменную, а потом добавили к s, тогда бы был вариант, о котором Вы подумали.

Comment: Вот как. А я думал, что, когда создается строка из различных данных-не строк, есть промежуточный этап по созданию всего в отдельные строки, а уже затем - создание одной строки. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте посмотрим чем будет заниматься JVM при выполнении этого задания. Декомпиляция примера дает такой результат:

```
public class Mounds {
    public Mounds() {  // тут конструктор по умолчанию
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s = new String();

        for(Object i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
            sb.append((String)i);  // а тут сюрприз!
        }

    }
}
```

Хотя классическое описание операции объединения строк с помощью оператора `+` предполагает следующую конструкцию:

```
s = new StringBuilder(s).append(" ").append((String)i)).toString()
```

в которой будет создано аж три объекта:

- сам `new StringBuilder()`
- новая строка `(String)i`
- и `new String()`в результате работы последнего  `toString()`,

мы видим что компилятор не стал размениваться на подобные мелочи и использовал имеющийся `StringBuilder` чтобы сократить количество объектов и операций к мнимому. Т.о. каждый цикл создается только новый объект `String` в момент преобразования числа к строке, и  ответ 1000 похож на правду.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробное объяснение!